# display content when window width is more than certain value - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

html

```
<div id="navBar">
    <div class="navBarStyles">
        <ul class="mainNavBar">
            <li><div class="menu-icon">z</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">WORKS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ARTICLES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">EXTRA</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
@media only screen
    and (max-width : 500px) {

        #navBar .mainNavBar li ul{
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #navBar .mainNavBar li ul a{
            color: #666666;
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            width: 50px;
        }
        .mainNavBar{
            width: 500px;
        }
        #navBar .mainNavBar li ul{
            display: none;  /*hide*/
        }
    }

.menu-icon:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

jquery

```
$(function() {                       
  $(".menu-icon").click(function() {  
    $("#navBar .mainNavBar li ul").toggle();     
  });
});

if($(window).width() > 500){
$(".mainNavBar").show();
```

}

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aAVV7/)

[changed condition - still not working](http://jsfiddle.net/aAVV7/2/)

Above code works fine, the only problem is when the width is less than `500` and user clicks on the `z` button to show the menu, then again clicks back to hide it, and the window is re-sized to greater than `500` the buttons doesn't show back. Please help. Need to fix the if statement in jquery code.

Comment: Why not hide/show the relevant elements using the CSS media query?

Comment: You have to also remove display none in css

Comment: tried this but forgot to add !important, and @Surjith SM nailed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use another media query to do this.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/aAVV7/1/)**

CSS

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 500px) {
 #navBar .mainNavBar li ul {
   display: block!important;
 }    
}
```

The reason I've given `!important` is jquery is adding inline CSS to show and hide. So we need this to override.

If you don't want to use `!importnat`, Then you can try `toggleClass`

Answer (score 1):

Here you had pass below condition

```
if($(window).width() > 500){
    $("#navBar .mainNavBar li ul").show();
}
```

That means when window width is more than 500 that time sub menu is display otherwise it does not display.
So you have to change in this condition. like

```
   if($(window).width() > 200){
        $("#navBar .mainNavBar li ul").show();
   }
```

Or Change in Css.

```
#navBar .mainNavBar li ul{
     display: none;  /*hide*/
 }
```

Here remove display none.

```
#navBar .mainNavBar li ul{
         display: block;  /*hide*/
}
```